# Having multiple domains point to single PHP script

Tags: domain-name-system, php, domain-name

I would like to have multiple domains point to a single PHP script, then I can use the PHP script to determine which content to show automatically.

For example, my main domain could by `mycoolscript.com`

I'd want my clients to be able to use their own domains, such as:

```
coolclient.com
funclient.com
niceclient.com
```

I want each of these domains to actually point to:

```
mycoolscript.com/client.php?domain=coolclient.com
mycoolscript.com/client.php?domain=funclient.com
mycoolscript.com/client.php?domain=niceclient.com
```

This way, I can show content based on the `domain` variable.

How do I do this properly? I'm assuming it will take some CNAME logic or something. I'm not a server/domain name expert though. Also I'm going to want subpage URL's to work too, such as `coolclient.com/about-us`, but I can probably make all of that work with PHP alone.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to put the domain in a query string. It is already available in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid handling this with CNAME records. It's going to be very difficult to scale, or change in the future if you do.

These kind of scenarios are exactly why web servers pass this information to PHP. I'm not aware of any common web servers that don't.

Simply use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in your PHP script and point all your domains at the same server.

Answer (score 0):

In DNS, you point each domain's A record to the IP address of your webserver.

Then, you have a virtual host in your web server that is the default virtual host, that is, all domains that are not otherwise configured in the webserver, are processed with this virtual host.

Then, in your PHP script you use the `HTTP_HOST` header to determine what is the hostname in the request and process the request accordingly.